# Qt5.9.1 + CUDA8.0: Random Crashes

Tags: qt5, qthread, xcb

I am trying to do some processing on the GPU with CUDA (version 8.0, GPU GTX980). The display is connected to this GPU. My Qt5 (version 5.9.1) application basically works fine, but randomly crashes.

It is a very basic program. 
Until now, I only do data transfers with CUDA, no kernel execution.
A Qt main loop and a QThread. The QThread is running a while loop, where it waits for a signal with `QThread::msleep(1)`.

I tried the two different paradigms of using QThread (subclassing and moveToThread) with the same result. 
I carefully seperated the code to maintain thread-safety (CUDA only accessed in QThread) and use signal/slot for the communication between main loop and QThread.

Eventually, I can also crash the application by moving the mouse onto the the GUI window.
When I investigate with GDB, I see different backtraces. Two examples below.

Backtrace No 1:

```
Thread 1 "ViterbiPredicto" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff67fa9a4 in QWindow::screen() const () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff67fa9a4 in QWindow::screen() const () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#1  0x00007ffff67e5521 in QPlatformWindow::screen() const () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#2  0x00007fffefa26faa in QXcbWindow::handleClientMessageEvent(xcb_client_message_event_t const*) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#3  0x00007fffefa1253b in QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fffefa12d9c in QXcbConnection::processXcbEvents() ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff62323c1 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff6fc94bc in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff6fd08e7 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff6206eb8 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff620954b in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff6259ad3 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff176f197 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff176f3f0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff176f49c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff625911f in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007ffff62054aa in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff620dd34 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x0000000000404bc1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf08) at ../ViterbiPredictor/main.cpp:10
```

Backtrace No 2:

```
ViterbiPredictor': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000074ab00 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ffff4eee7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7ffff4ef737a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7ffff4efb53c]
/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x280563)[0x7ffff620e563]
/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x2806cd)[0x7ffff620e6cd]
/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN16QCoreApplication9postEventEP7QObjectP6QEventi+0x35e)[0x7ffff620a2ee]
/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv+0x4c0)[0x7ffff62312d0]
/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5(+0x395d5)[0x7fffefa0e5d5]
/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0xaa84a)[0x7ffff603884a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7ffff5ae96ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ffff4f7e3dd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040d000 r-xp 00000000 00:2e 17434727                           build-ViterbiPredictor-Qt_5_9_1_in_PATH_System-Debug/ViterbiPredictor
0060d000-0060e000 rw-p 0000d000 00:2e 17434727                           build-ViterbiPredictor-Qt_5_9_1_in_PATH_System-Debug/ViterbiPredictor
0060e000-00c5a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
200000000-200100000 rw-s 2fc8c1000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200100000-200104000 rw-s 2f78b3000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200104000-200120000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200120000-200520000 rw-s 2f78b7000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200520000-200524000 rw-s 2faed6000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200524000-200540000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200540000-200940000 rw-s 2faeda000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200940000-200944000 rw-s 2fa4c7000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200944000-200960000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200960000-200d60000 rw-s 2fa4cf000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200d60000-200d64000 rw-s 37866c000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
200d64000-200d80000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
200d80000-201180000 rw-s 32e89d000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
201180000-201184000 rw-s 2f9da0000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
201184000-2011a0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2011a0000-2015a0000 rw-s 2f9dac000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
2015a0000-2015a4000 rw-s 2f59b9000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
2015a4000-2015c0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2015c0000-2019c0000 rw-s 2f5a4d000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
2019c0000-2019c4000 rw-s 31f250000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
2019c4000-2019e0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
2019e0000-201de0000 rw-s 31f25c000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
201de0000-201de4000 rw-s 32e4c5000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
201de4000-201e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
201e00000-202200000 rw-s 32e4dd000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202200000-202204000 rw-s 42a322000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202204000-202220000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202220000-202620000 rw-s 42a32e000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202620000-202624000 rw-s 2f9e8a000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202624000-202640000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202640000-202a40000 rw-s 2f9e96000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202a40000-202a44000 rw-s 2f58e1000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202a44000-202a60000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202a60000-202e60000 rw-s 2f58ed000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202e60000-202e64000 rw-s 2fcd38000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
202e64000-202e80000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
202e80000-203280000 rw-s 2fcec4000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203280000-203380000 rw-s 309511000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203380000-203480000 rw-s 32e81f000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203480000-203580000 rw-s 2fc82a000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203580000-203680000 rw-s 2f352c000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203680000-203780000 rw-s 326faf000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203780000-203860000 rw-s 322d33000 00:06 19655                           /dev/nvidiactl
203860000-203960000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 251175                           /dev/zero (deleted)
203960000-203a60000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 251176                           /dev/zero (deleted)
203a60000-900000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffb4000000-7fffb4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffb4021000-7fffb8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffbc000000-7fffbc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffbc021000-7fffc0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc0000000-7fffc0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc0021000-7fffc4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc7205000-7fffc7206000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc7206000-7fffc7a06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc7a06000-7fffc7be2000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 9830430                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fffc7be2000-7fffc7bed000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 795491                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7fffc7bed000-7fffc7dec000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 795491                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7fffc7dec000-7fffc7ded000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 795491                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7fffc7ded000-7fffc7dee000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 795491                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
7fffc7dee000-7fffc7df4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc7df4000-7fffc7dff000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 801096                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7fffc7dff000-7fffc7ffe000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 801096                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7fffc7ffe000-7fffc7fff000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 801096                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7fffc7fff000-7fffc8000000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 801096                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
7fffc8000000-7fffc850c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc850c000-7fffcc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffcc02c000-7fffcc02d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffcc02d000-7fffcc82d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffcc82d000-7fffcc843000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 787747                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7fffcc843000-7fffcca42000 ---p 00016000 08:01 787747                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7fffcca42000-7fffcca43000 r--p 00015000 08:01 787747                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7fffcca43000-7fffcca44000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 787747                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7fffcca44000-7fffcca46000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffcca46000-7fffcca4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 801103                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7fffcca4e000-7fffccc4d000 ---p 00008000 08:01 801103                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7fffccc4d000-7fffccc4e000 r--p 00007000 08:01 801103                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7fffccc4e000-7fffccc4f000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 801103                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
7fffccc4f000-7fffccc50000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffccc50000-7fffcd450000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffcd450000-7fffce7e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4228861                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-glcore.so.367.57
7fffce7e9000-7fffce809000 rwxp 01399000 08:01 4228861                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-glcore.so.367.57
7fffce809000-7fffcebaa000 r-xp 013b9000 08:01 4228861                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-glcore.so.367.57
7fffcebaa000-7fffceda9000 ---p 0175a000 08:01 4228861                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-glcore.so.367.57
7fffceda9000-7fffcf171000 rw-p 01759000 08:01 4228861                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-glcore.so.367.57
7fffcf171000-7fffcf189000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffcf189000-7fffd4000000 rw-s 00000000 00:16 71197                      /dev/shm/jack-1000-0
7fffd4000000-7fffd4022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffd4022000-7fffd8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffd8000000-7fffd8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffd8021000-7fffdc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffdc000000-7fffdc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffdc021000-7fffe0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0091000-7fffe0094000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4228827                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.367.57
7fffe0094000-7fffe0294000 ---p 00003000 08:01 4228827                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.367.57
7fffe0294000-7fffe0295000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4228827                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.367.57
7fffe0295000-7fffe035d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4228820                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGLX_nvidia.so.367.57
7fffe035d000-7fffe0391000 rwxp 000c8000 08:01 4228820                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGLX_nvidia.so.367.57
7fffe0391000-7fffe03a4000 r-xp 000fc000 08:01 4228820                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGLX_nvidia.so.367.57
7fffe03a4000-7fffe05a4000 ---p 0010f000 08:01 4228820                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGLX_nvidia.so.367.57
7fffe05a4000-7fffe05cc000 rw-p 0010f000 08:01 4228820                    /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGLX_nvidia.so.367.57
7fffe05cc000-7fffe05d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0607000-7fffe0608000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0608000-7fffe0e08000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0e08000-7fffe0e09000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0e09000-7fffe0ecb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0ecb000-7fffe0ecc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0ecc000-7fffe0f4c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0f4c000-7fffe0f4d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0f4d000-7fffe0fcd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0fcd000-7fffe0fce000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe0fce000-7fffe17ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe17ce000-7fffe17cf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe17cf000-7fffe1fcf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe1fcf000-7fffe2005000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4589043                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fffe2005000-7fffe2205000 ---p 00036000 08:01 4589043                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fffe2205000-7fffe220a000 r--p 00036000 08:01 4589043                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fffe220a000-7fffe220b000 rw-p 0003b000 08:01 4589043                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fffe220b000-7fffe223b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4589041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fffe223b000-7fffe243b000 ---p 00030000 08:01 4589041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fffe243b000-7fffe243c000 r--p 00030000 08:01 4589041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fffe243c000-7fffe243e000 rw-p 00031000 08:01 4589041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fffe243e000-7fffe2480000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2762282                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so
7fffe2480000-7fffe267f000 ---p 00042000 08:01 2762282                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so
7fffe267f000-7fffe2681000 r--p 00041000 08:01 2762282                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so
7fffe2681000-7fffe2682000 rw-p 00043000 08:01 2762282                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so
7fffe2682000-7fffe2699000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4195429                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7fffe2699000-7fffe2898000 ---p 00017000 08:01 4195429                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7fffe2898000-7fffe2899000 r--p 00016000 08:01 4195429                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7fffe2899000-7fffe289a000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 4195429                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
7fffe289a000-7fffe28be000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4204382                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7fffe28be000-7fffe2abd000 ---p 00024000 08:01 4204382                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7fffe2abd000-7fffe2abf000 r--p 00023000 08:01 4204382                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7fffe2abf000-7fffe2ac0000 rw-p 00025000 08:01 4204382                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
7fffe2ac0000-7fffe2ac6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4204224                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7fffe2ac6000-7fffe2cc6000 ---p 00006000 08:01 4204224                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7fffe2cc6000-7fffe2cc7000 r--p 00006000 08:01 4204224                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7fffe2cc7000-7fffe2cc8000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 4204224                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1.3.3
7fffe2cc8000-7fffe2cf8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205035                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fffe2cf8000-7fffe2ef7000 ---p 00030000 08:01 4205035                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fffe2ef7000-7fffe2ef8000 r--p 0002f000 08:01 4205035                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fffe2ef8000-7fffe2ef9000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 4205035                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fffe2ef9000-7fffe2efc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4194849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7fffe2efc000-7fffe30fb000 ---p 00003000 08:01 4194849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7fffe30fb000-7fffe30fc000 r--p 00002000 08:01 4194849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7fffe30fc000-7fffe30fd000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4194849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7fffe30fd000-7fffe316c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4197461                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7fffe316c000-7fffe336b000 ---p 0006f000 08:01 4197461                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7fffe336b000-7fffe336e000 r--p 0006e000 08:01 4197461                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7fffe336e000-7fffe336f000 rw-p 00071000 08:01 4197461                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3
7fffe336f000-7fffe339d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4204849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7fffe339d000-7fffe359d000 ---p 0002e000 08:01 4204849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7fffe359d000-7fffe359f000 r--p 0002e000 08:01 4204849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7fffe359f000-7fffe35a0000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 4204849                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5
7fffe35a0000-7fffe35fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4201082                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7fffe35fc000-7fffe37fc000 ---p 0005c000 08:01 4201082                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7fffe37fc000-7fffe37fd000 r--p 0005c000 08:01 4201082                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7fffe37fd000-7fffe37fe000 rw-p 0005d000 08:01 4201082                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
7fffe37fe000-7fffe382a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4204067                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7fffe382a000-7fffe3a29000 ---p 0002c000 08:01 4204067                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7fffe3a29000-7fffe3a2c000 r--p 0002b000 08:01 4204067                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7fffe3a2c000-7fffe3a2d000 rw-p 0002e000 08:01 4204067                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0.0.1
7fffe3a2d000-7fffe3a34000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4204345                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fffe3a34000-7fffe3c33000 ---p 00007000 08:01 4204345                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fffe3c33000-7fffe3c34000 r--p 00006000 08:01 4204345                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fffe3c34000-7fffe3c35000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 4204345                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fffe3c35000-7fffe3c3d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205410                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7fffe3c3d000-7fffe3e3d000 ---p 00008000 08:01 4205410                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7fffe3e3d000-7fffe3e3e000 r--p 00008000 08:01 4205410                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7fffe3e3e000-7fffe3e3f000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 4205410                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
7fffe3e3f000-7fffe3e41000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205414                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7fffe3e41000-7fffe4041000 ---p 00002000 08:01 4205414                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7fffe4041000-7fffe4042000 r--p 00002000 08:01 4205414                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7fffe4042000-7fffe4043000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 4205414                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
7fffe4043000-7fffe40e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205014                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7fffe40e2000-7fffe42e2000 ---p 0009f000 08:01 4205014                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7fffe42e2000-7fffe42ea000 r--p 0009f000 08:01 4205014                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7fffe42ea000-7fffe42eb000 rw-p 000a7000 08:01 4205014                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
7fffe42eb000-7fffe42f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205221                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7fffe42f3000-7fffe44f2000 ---p 00008000 08:01 4205221                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7fffe44f2000-7fffe44f3000 r--p 00007000 08:01 4205221                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7fffe44f3000-7fffe44f4000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 4205221                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0.2.4
7fffe44f4000-7fffe450b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 801107                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fffe450b000-7fffe470b000 ---p 00017000 08:01 801107                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fffe470b000-7fffe470c000 r--p 00017000 08:01 801107                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fffe470c000-7fffe470d000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 801107                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fffe470d000-7fffe470f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe470f000-7fffe478a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4204848                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7fffe478a000-7fffe498a000 ---p 0007b000 08:01 4204848                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7fffe498a000-7fffe498f000 r--p 0007b000 08:01 4204848                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7fffe498f000-7fffe4990000 rw-p 00080000 08:01 4204848                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9
7fffe4990000-7fffe499c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205310                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7fffe499c000-7fffe4b9b000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 4205310                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7fffe4b9b000-7fffe4b9d000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 4205310                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7fffe4b9d000-7fffe4b9e000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 4205310                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
7fffe4b9e000-7fffe4b9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4194563                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7fffe4b9f000-7fffe4d9e000 ---p 00001000 08:01 4194563                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7fffe4d9e000-7fffe4d9f000 r--p 00000000 08:01 4194563                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7fffe4d9f000-7fffe4da0000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 4194563                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
7fffe4da0000-7fffe4da4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205312                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7fffe4da4000-7fffe4fa3000 ---p 00004000 08:01 4205312                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7fffe4fa3000-7fffe4fa4000 r--p 00003000 08:01 4205312                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7fffe4fa4000-7fffe4fa8000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 4205312                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0.0.0
7fffe4fa8000-7fffe4fe5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4205432                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7fffe4fe5000-7fffe51e4000 ---p 0003d000 08:01 4205432                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7fffe51e4000-7fffe51e6000 r--p 0003c000 08:01 4205432                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7fffe51e6000-7fffe51e7000 rw-p 0003e000 08:01 4205432                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
7fffe51e7000-7fffe51e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4203965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7fffe51e9000-7fffe53e8000 ---p 00002000 08:01 4203965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7fffe53e8000-7fffe53e9000 r--p 00001000 08:01 4203965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7fffe53e9000-7fffe53ea000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 4203965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7fffe53ea000-7fffe53ec000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4203961                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
7fffe53ec000-7fffe55eb000 ---p 00002000 08:01 4203961                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
7fffe55eb000-7fffe55ec000 r--p 00001000 08:01 4203961                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0
Thread 2 "QXcbEventReader" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffed852700 (LWP 7646)]
0x00007ffff4eac428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff4eac428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff4eae02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff4eee7ea in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff5007e98 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff4ef737a in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=<optimized out>, ptr=<optimized out>, 
    str=0x7ffff5004c6f "free(): invalid pointer", action=3) at malloc.c:5006
#4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3867
#5  0x00007ffff4efb53c in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2968
#6  0x00007ffff620e563 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff620e6cd in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff620a2ee in QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject*, QEvent*, int) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff62312d0 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) ()
   from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007fffefa0e5d5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff603884a in ?? () from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007ffff5ae96ba in start_thread (arg=0x7fffed852700) at pthread_create.c:333
#13 0x00007ffff4f7e3dd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

Since I see XCB a lot, I suspect that there is some problem with the sharing of the GPU for the display device and for CUDA?

Can anyone help?

Is there some code I should show?

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with CUDA. All the backtraces show the segfaults being generated within libQt5Core. If there was a problem with the X11 driver and CUDA interactions, you would see them as errors in the syslog, not within a userspace segfault.

Comment: I added it to describe the whole scenario. I am not very familiar with the mechanics of X11 and XCB, but I read in some blog post, that using the GPU for display and CUDA might be problamatic.

Comment: The only thing the display driver will do is kill your process if its GPU occupancy exceeds the watchdog timer limit. But you say you are not even running kernels at this point, so that is impossible

Comment: what is impossible?

Comment: Ok, that means CUDA should be out of the picture. Any suggestion, where I should start to look?

Comment: I only know about CUDA, sorry. But I will remove the tag if there is no objection

Comment: Small, not helpful data point: QWindow::screen() is implemented as `return d->parentWindow ? d->parentWindow->screen() : d->topLevelScreen.data();` where `d` comes from `Q_D(const QWindow);`. This shouldn't crash, as far as I can see. How about "memory corruption" as an explanation for this?